# Compile Kotlin Native code to other targets

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

My question is, if valid Kotlin Native Code is also valid Code for compiling for JVM, JS, …

If not, I am wondering where the differences are.

If yes, I am wondering why we need three implementations for Kotlin Multiplatform Libraries https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html
Couldn’t we just use the Native code for all three then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are common APIs and libraries that are available for all platforms, and there are APIs and libraries available for just one or several platforms. The difference is in whether or not they need platform-specific functionality to work. For example, a native app can't do JVM-based reflection and a JVM app can't do native memory management.